# How to import html page as pdf in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, graph, amcharts

I have an **html page which contains graph** created with [Amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/v3/)
and I need to generate pdf of my html page. Amcharts have provided 
[this](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/exporting-pdf-with-multiple-charts-and-related-info/) link for exporting html in javascript my question is there is any way to **export a page from server-side i.e nodejs**.

There is no such tutorial in a given site and so far I have tried [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html-to-pdf) plugin but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amcharts has a [knowledgebase article](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/exporting-pdf-with-multiple-charts-and-related-info/) showing how to do this. If you prefer an alternative you can try [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake#images) and build up the pdf with the png's yourself.

Once you have the pdf you can serve the file over an endpoint on node pretty easily, eg [using express](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/03/remote-pfs-node-js-express/).